# Android Studio- OnClickListener Not Detecting Click

Tags: javascript, android, button, web, onclicklistener

My application has two buttons that do various tasks the first button works (id: "CalcBtn") however, the second button (id:web) which I want to open a browser does not work. When I open the emulator, the clicker for the second button does not launch the website or even detect the click itself.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText editText;
EditText editText2;
EditText editText3;

Button CalcBtn;
Button web;

TextView Output;

double a, b, c, d, x1, x2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

    CalcBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CalcBtn);
    web = (Button) findViewById(R.id.web);

    Output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Output);

    CalcBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!editText.getText().toString().equals("") && !editText2.getText().toString().equals("")
                    && !editText3.getText().toString().equals("")) {

                a = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());
                b = Double.parseDouble(editText2.getText().toString());
                c = Double.parseDouble(editText3.getText().toString());

                d = Math.pow(b, 2) - 4*a*c;

                if (d == 0) {
                    x1 = -b / (2*a);
                    Output.setText("d = " + d + "\nx = " + x1);
                } else if (d < 0) {
                    Output.setText("No Real Roots");
                } else if (d > 0) {
                    x1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(d))/(2*a);
                    x2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(d))/(2*a);
                    Output.setText("d = " + d + "\nx = " + x1 + "\nx2 = " + x2);

                    web.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent web = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.purplemath.com/modules/quadform.htm"));
                            startActivity(web);
                        }
                    });

                }
            }
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: you can't perform `onClickListener` inside another `onClickListener`.

Comment: @vrundpurohit he can perform nested onClickListener but it is not a good practice...

Comment: if you want to perform part of web button on your calBtn's click event than why your are implementing clickListener of web button. just do your logic inside that condition rather than performing click event of web button.

Answer (score 0):

put your `web` button click event outside of click event `CalcBtn`.
`web` button click listener is inside of `CalcBtn` click event, which will be not detect even.

Web button click event

```
 web.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Intent web = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.purplemath.com/modules/quadform.htm"));
                                startActivity(web);
                            }
                        });
```

CalcBtn button click event

```
 CalcBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!editText.getText().toString().equals("") && !editText2.getText().toString().equals("")
                    && !editText3.getText().toString().equals("")) {

                a = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());
                b = Double.parseDouble(editText2.getText().toString());
                c = Double.parseDouble(editText3.getText().toString());

                d = Math.pow(b, 2) - 4*a*c;

                if (d == 0) {
                    x1 = -b / (2*a);
                    Output.setText("d = " + d + "\nx = " + x1);
                } else if (d < 0) {
                    Output.setText("No Real Roots");
                } else if (d > 0) {
                    x1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(d))/(2*a);
                    x2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(d))/(2*a);
                    Output.setText("d = " + d + "\nx = " + x1 + "\nx2 = " + x2);



                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: The button is still not working .-. I moved the web onClickListener above the CalcBtn OnClickListener, however its still not detecting it. Not sure if I inputted it correctly.

Comment: This is a good suggestion for style, but I don't think that it is your problem. Use your debugger or trace execution to make sure that you are taking the branches and executing the code that you think you are. I just did a quick mock-up and setting the click listener from within another works on an emulator running API 23.